# django error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a' " while posting form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am getting this error while form submission. I know what exactly is causing this error but i seem to be lost here. Actually im trying to use the M2M field as a charfield in my form. According to documentation, the M2M field takes only the list of valid ids and im passing a list of texts. This is the main cause for the error as far as i am informed. Any idea how i can get rid of this error

I have a model structure of:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, null=True, blank=True)
    tag_name = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

and in forms.py I have:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag_name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Question

    def clean_tag_name(self):
        data  = self.cleaned_data
        tag_name = data.get('tag_name', None)
        if tag_name is not None:
            for tags in tag_name.split(','):
                try:
                    tag = Tag.objects.get(tag_name=tags)
                except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                    tag = Tag.objects.create(tag_name = tags)

        return tag_name

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ints = super(QuestionForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        tags = self.cleaned_data.get('tag_name', None)
        if tags is not None:
            for tag in tags.split(","):
                tag = QuestionForm.objects.create(name=tag_name)
                ints.tag_name.add(tag)
                ints.save()
        return ints
```

Comment: Which line you got that error? Please put the whole error.

Comment: Actually the error is in django server. `../site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 537`

Comment: no its in your codes, ignore that line.

Comment: The error is when i input a list of texts in the tag_name field in the form and post it. The value gets posted in the database but leaving behind an error in the frontend. The error is beacause when i input the list of texts the M2M field in the database rejects it because it only accepts the valid ids that is integers. Thus, the error appear. Now i need a way to solve this..

Comment: You probably want to return `tag` instead of `tag_name` in your `clean_tag_name` method

Comment: the error is still same.

Comment: What kind of data you put in the form? Show us an example.

Comment: It doesn't take any data. I've tried with `a b c` and `a,b,c` formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet has a few flaws:

You can't do `QuestionForm.objects.create(name=tag_name)` because `QuestionForm` is not a model and has no `objects` attribute.

You probably wanted to write `Question.objects.create(name=tag_name)` but that wouldn't work as well because `Question` has no field `name` and you don't have a variable called `tag_name` at that point.

Furthermore, in your `clean()` method you make sure that the tags the user had entered exist in the database, but in your `save()` method you are trying to add the tag names (as in: the strings) and not the tag objects to the M2M field. You can't do that. The `.add()` method of the M2M field expects an instance of the `Tag` model. This means, in your `.save()` method, you have to split your tag strings again, then fetch the `Tag` objects from the database and add those instances to the `Question` instance you just created.

Try this instead:

First change the `class Meta`:

```
class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ['topic', 'question']
```

This makes sure that the form doesn't try to save the `tag_name` field. This is important, otherwise the `super()` call below would try to add something like `tag1, tag2, foobar` to the M2M field, which is not possible (remmeber, you can't add strings to an M2M field, you can only add instances).

Then change the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = super(QuestionForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    tags = self.cleaned_data.get('tag_name', None)
    if tags:
        for tag in tags.split(","):
            tag = Tag.objects.get(tag_name=tag)
            obj.tag_name.add(tag)
    return obj
```

Comment: thats very informative and nicely explained. I made a lot of mistakes and thanks for pointing that out. really appreciated myan!!thanks again.